# Ignore unresolved symbols with Clojure reader

Tags: clojure

I have an app that logs Clojure maps to a log file via `prn`.  A contrived entry from the log might be:

```
{:foo "bar" 
 :baz [:quux] 
 :body #<HttpInput org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput@2a4bd173>}
```

I'd like to be able to paste this into a repl to inspect the "simple" keys and values, but the reader chokes on `#<` values.

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException:
  Unable to resolve symbol: HttpInput in this context
```

I don't care about the `#<` values. Is there a way to get the reader to ignore them, or give me a chance to deal with them directly (sort of like `*data-readers*`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to make this input work with the reader without manually editing the log output. The default behavior for `prn` for unrecognized datatypes is to output something of the form:

`#<(.getSimpleName (class o)) (str o)>`

The `#` character indicates a reader macro, which dispatches on the following character, and the `<` character indicates an unreadable form; the reader will always throw an exception when it encounters this.

Your best bet might be to alter the logging for your application, to print something more readable. One way of doing this is providing an implementation of the [`print-method`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/print-method) multimethod for your target class, e.g.:

```
(defmethod print-method org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput [o w]
  (print-method {:type "HttpInput"
                 :request-uri (-> o ._connection .getRequest .getUri str)}
                w))
```

(This might not work for the protected field `_connection`, but hopefully you get the picture.)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was hoping for something that'd work with no upfront thought, but I agree it's probably better to just log something more sensible.

Comment: I wish all my programs would work with no up-front thought :)